# Google Analytics with Python only shows the last dimension

Tags: python, google-analytics, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-python-client

So I'm using a slightly modified version of the [Hello Analytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/installed-py) python script.

The only differences are that I have a few more "expressions" in the metrics and I'm trying to add a dimension. everything works fine except when I print out everything in the last for loop it only shows the last dimension.

So instead of getting a list of all the dimensions with there metrics I get only the last one.

```
ga:city: Ho Chi Minh City
ga:users: 19
ga:newUsers: 19
ga:sessionsPerUser: 1.263157894736842
ga:sessions: 24
ga:bounces: 18
ga:bounceRate: 75.0
ga:avgSessionDuration: 40.708333333333336
```

Here is the code sample

```
"""Hello Analytics Reporting API V4."""

import argparse

from apiclient.discovery import build
import httplib2
from oauth2client import client
from oauth2client import file
from oauth2client import tools

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly']
DISCOVERY_URI = ('https://analyticsreporting.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest')
CLIENT_SECRETS_PATH = 'client_secrets.json' # Path to client_secrets.json file.
VIEW_ID = '170823765'


def initialize_analyticsreporting():
  """Initializes the analyticsreporting service object.

  Returns:
    analytics an authorized analyticsreporting service object.
  """
  # Parse command-line arguments.
  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
      formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter,
      parents=[tools.argparser])
  flags = parser.parse_args([])

  # Set up a Flow object to be used if we need to authenticate.
  flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(
      CLIENT_SECRETS_PATH, scope=SCOPES,
      message=tools.message_if_missing(CLIENT_SECRETS_PATH))

  # Prepare credentials, and authorize HTTP object with them.
  # If the credentials don't exist or are invalid run through the native client
  # flow. The Storage object will ensure that if successful the good
  # credentials will get written back to a file.
  storage = file.Storage('analyticsreporting.dat')
  credentials = storage.get()
  if credentials is None or credentials.invalid:
    credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, storage, flags)
  http = credentials.authorize(http=httplib2.Http())

  # Build the service object.
  analytics = build('analytics', 'v4', http=http, discoveryServiceUrl=DISCOVERY_URI)

  return analytics

def get_report(analytics):
    # Use the Analytics Service Object to query the Analytics Reporting API V4.
    return analytics.reports().batchGet(
        body={
            'reportRequests': [
                {
                    'viewId': VIEW_ID,
                    'dateRanges': [{'startDate': '30daysAgo', 'endDate': 'today'}],
                    'metrics': [
                        {'expression': 'ga:users'},
                        {'expression': 'ga:newUsers'},
                        {'expression': 'ga:sessionsPerUser'},
                        {'expression': 'ga:sessions'},
                        {'expression': 'ga:bounces'},
                        {'expression': 'ga:bounceRate'},
                        {'expression': 'ga:avgSessionDuration'},
                    ],
                    "dimensions": [
                        {"name": "ga:city"}
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ).execute()


def print_response(response):
    """Parses and prints the Analytics Reporting API V4 response"""

    for report in response.get('reports', []):

        columnHeader = report.get('columnHeader', {})
        dimensionHeaders = columnHeader.get('dimensions', [])
        metricHeaders = columnHeader.get('metricHeader', {}).get('metricHeaderEntries', [])
        rows = report.get('data', {}).get('rows', [])


        for row in rows:
            dimensions = row.get('dimensions', [])
            dateRangeValues = row.get('metrics', [])

        for header, dimension in zip(dimensionHeaders, dimensions):
            print(header + ': ' + dimension)

        for i, values in enumerate(dateRangeValues):
            for metricHeader, value in zip(metricHeaders, values.get('values')):
                print(metricHeader.get('name') + ': ' + value)


def main():

  analytics = initialize_analyticsreporting()
  response = get_report(analytics)
  print_response(response)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

I'm new to both Google Analytics and Python so I apologize if this is a no-brainier question.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an error in my spacing. not used to working with python missed the fact that I should have indented the part were it goes through the results and prints them out.

So instead of

```
    for row in rows:
        dimensions = row.get('dimensions', [])
        dateRangeValues = row.get('metrics', [])

    for header, dimension in zip(dimensionHeaders, dimensions):
        print(header + ': ' + dimension)

    for i, values in enumerate(dateRangeValues):

        for metricHeader, value in zip(metricHeaders, values.get('values')):
            print(metricHeader.get('name') + ': ' + value)
```

It should be

```
 for row in rows:
            dimensions = row.get('dimensions', [])
            dateRangeValues = row.get('metrics', [])

            for header, dimension in zip(dimensionHeaders, dimensions):
                print(header + ': ' + dimension)

            for i, values in enumerate(dateRangeValues):

                for metricHeader, value in zip(metricHeaders, values.get('values')):
                    print(metricHeader.get('name') + ': ' + value)
```